# add text on imageview and save it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-image

i am trying to create an application which add text to image. In this my image is coming from gallery and text is added by user. For that i have created my layout as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

activity is as:

```
public class AddText extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_text);

    findViewById(R.id.relativelayout).setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap finalImg = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout).getDrawingCache();

    String save_location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/texted";
    File dir = new File(save_location);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File f = new File(dir, "tmp.jpg");
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        finalImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now i want to save this entire image with text. what is the way to save image with text?

error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your Layout should have the Drawing cache enabled set to true. You can set it through the setter `View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` Then you should able to retrieve the `View`'s content with the `View.getDrawingCache()`. The method returns a Bitmap instance representing the `View`'s content. You can use `Bitmap.compress(..)`, in order to store it.

Comment: where i should write `View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`

Comment: after setContentView.. findViewById(R.id.relativelayout).setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: it is giving me error. Although image is saved on my specified location bt that is also invalid image..

Comment: there is no need. Edit your question and post all the relevant snippet of code

Answer (score -1):

After the image selection, provide the user an edit text box where he enters the text. Instead of relative layout use Frame layout so that text will appear over the image.

You have to convert the view into a Bitmap

here is the code

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v)
 { 
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas c = new Canvas(b); v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width,v.getLayoutParams().height); v.draw(c); 
return b;
 }
```

Comment: Through FrameLayout i can put text on image but how to save that image containing text??

Comment: Provide a done button at the bottom, when the user presses that the text in edit text box should be displayed as a text view on the image. Initially the textview will be in Gone mode. After button click Edit text box will go into gone mode.

Comment: Try this public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}

Comment: use v.getWidth() instead of v.getLayoutParams().width and similar for height

Comment: even if that dosen't work try this...v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

Comment: In loadBitmapFromView(View v) method